# Deleting clickable panes in JavaFX (In controller)

Tags: javafx

Im setting up a game and I have tried numerous ways to attempt to get rid of these panes that are only needed once per "turn". I need a way to inverse a function that creates multiple panes in every cell. I've tried this:

```
      for (int i = 0 ; i < numCols ; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < numRows; j++) {
                    addPane(i, j);
                }
            }
        }


        private void addPane(int colIndex, int rowIndex) {
            Pane pane = new Pane();
            pane.setOnMouseEntered(e -> {
                System.out.printf("Mouse enetered cell [%d, %d]%n", colIndex, rowIndex);
            });
            grid.add(pane, colIndex, rowIndex);
        }
private void removePane(int colIndex, int rowIndex) {
            Pane pane2 = new Pane();
            pane.getChildren().remove(pane2);
        }

      for (int i = 0 ; i < numCols ; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < numRows; j++) {
                    removePane(i, j);
                }
            }
        }
```

I expect the panes to all be removed upon using the removePane function but nothing changes. The panes are still in each cell.

Comment: Seriously, I have no idea how this managed to compile...

Comment: If you want to seperate code blocks, just add a html comment in between (not intended with 4 spaces): `<!---->`. It seems like there are 3 seperate code snippets mashed together.

Comment: Why are you trying to remove `pane2`? You literally just created it and never added it to any other pane...

Answer (score 0):

`List.remove(Object)` works like this:

If there is a element in the list that matches the parameter passed to the method when compared using `equals`, it is removed.

Since `Pane` does not override the `equals` method, an element of the child list is removed iff the element passed is one of the objects in the list. Since you create a new `Pane` the `removePane` leaves the child list unchanged.

You need to remove the children of the `GridPane` using other means, e.g.

- using [the `clear` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#clear()) of the child list. This removes *all* of the children and won't work, if there are nodes you want to keep. If you know the index range of the children to remove, you can call `clear` on [a sublist](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#subList(int,int)) though.
- using [the `removeIf` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf(java.util.function.Predicate)). This allows you to pass a `Predicate` that is used to check, if an element should be removed or kept in the list.
- using the [`removeAll(Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection))/[`retainAll(Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) method passing a `Collection` of children you want to remove/keep. This requires you to keep track of the panes you want to remove/not remove in your code in some collection. You could e.g. add those nodes to a collection in the `addPane` method. Be sure to update this collection after the removal of the nodes from the `GridPane`'s child list unless they are needed later, since this is a potential source of a memory leak.
- ...

Comment: I tried changing  pane.getChildren().remove(pane2); to  pane.getChildren().removeAll(pane2); but nothing seems to change.

Comment: @enir I'm not refering to the varargs method added in `ObservableList` (unless you keep track of the children to remove in a `Node[]` array). I'm refering to the `removeAll(Collection)` method defined in `List`. If you're using vararg method, the issue is exactly the same as the one with using the `remove(Object)` method. (You've got the same issue, if you create a new `Collection` containing a object not in the child list btw)